# Sample programs written using python-bitcoinlib?

Tags: python

Where can I get source codes of programs written using the python-bitcoinlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the example folder in bitcoinlib repo
https://github.com/petertodd/python-bitcoinlib/tree/master/examples